# How to remove all special characters in a large French text file

Tags: python, regex, bash, unicode, data-cleaning

Given a large text file in French (>200GB) encoded in UTF-8 and normalised by unicode `NFC`, I want to remove all special characters except accented/unaccented alphabetical letters, numbers and punctuations using Python or Bash or whichever method that is faster. Previously, I do this task manually by scanning the text to identify if there is any special characters that I don't want and remove them using character codes like this:

```
def remove_special_chars(text):

    text = re.sub(chr(65533), '', text)
    text = re.sub(chr(9658), '', text) 
    text = re.sub(chr(9660), '', text)
    text = re.sub(chr(169), '', text)  

    return text
```

> � (char code 65533) ► (char code 9658) ▼ (char code 9660) © (char code 169) etc.

However, for a large text file, it is not possible to do it that way anymore. Therefore, I am thinking of removing all of the special characters by checking if a character is an (accented/unaccented) alphabetical letter or a number or a punctuation and removing if it is not. I tried the following but the command line does not execute.

```
grep -P -v '[^a-zA-Z0-9 àâäèéêëîïôœùûüÿçÀÂÄÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜŸÇ!"#\$%&\'\(\)\*\+,\\-\./:;<=>\?@\[\]\^_`\{\|\}\~]' file
```

Could you please help me on this problem? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Maybe `sed 's,[^[:alnum:][:punct:] ],,g' file > newfile`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But the `[:alnum:]` includes unaccented characters like `a-z` and `A-Z` while the text is in French so I would need accented characters like `éèàçîï...` as well.

Comment: So, that command will keep all the letters, digits, punctuation and a literal space.  Your `grep` command looks to written in this wake. What do *you* need if not that? What characters do you consider *special*?

Comment: hat if you try `sed 'y/áàâäçéèêëîïìôöóùúüñÂÀÄÇÉÈÊËÎÏÔÖÙÜÛÑ/aaaaceeeeiiiooouuunAAACEEEEIIOOUUUN/' $filein > $fileout`, this is what I use for my french input

Comment: I think it's easier to do the opposite: extracting everything that's not a special character, for this you can use easier regexes. Also maybe take a look at the nltk library which have the `nltk.tokenize.RegexpTokenizer` method.

Comment: Does "accented/unaccented alphabetical letters, numbers and punctuations" imply only _latin_ letters, _arabic_ numbers and _french_ punctuation? If `sed` supports Unicode categories see https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category

Comment: @Chelmy88 Could you please help me explain why there is several repeated letters of `a, e, i, o, u, E, E ...`? And also will that command keep all the punctuations? Because I would like to keep the punctuations as well.

Comment: @Plopp I'm not sure if I should apply tokenisation now for cleaning purpose. My data now is very noisy and includes many different special characters so I just want to get them removed first before doing further preprocessing steps.

Comment: @Sophil It will take letters in the first list (after the first slash), and replace it with the corresponding letters in the second list (after the second slash). Only these characters will be affected, so the punctuation is kept. In my version, it swill read `$filein` (replace with your file name) and write it to `$fileout` (replace with the desired output file name). so it will duplicate the 200GB file. It can be done "inplace", i.e. modify the input file, I can show you how to, but it is one shot, so you need to be sure...

Comment: @AmigoJack Yes, thank you for clarifying my question. The link that you suggested seems very useful! Thank you!

Comment: @Sophil Btw, on which OS are you running it?

Comment: Sorry, I realized I miss-understood your question. I understood that you wanted to replace accent with non-accent character.. My bad...

Comment: @Chelmy88 Thank you for your suggestion! So it will replace all the accented characters like `éàê ...` by the corresponding unaccented characters like `eae...`? However, I want to keep the French letters as they are, just removing the special characters like those of char codes 65533, 9658 etc. like in the question.

Comment: @Chelmy88 I'm using Linux now. Sorry my connection is bad now so I didn't get your previous comment :)

Comment: All the 3 symbols above are from the *So - Symbol, other* Unicode category. In Python, it is easy to install PyPi regex module, do `import regex` and then use `text = regex.sub(r'\p{So}+', '', text)`. In Linux, use `perl -i  -CSD -Mutf8 -pe 's/\p{So}+//g' file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All [the chars you want to remove](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%EF%BF%BD%E2%96%BA%E2%96%BC%C2%A9#title) belong to the [*Symbols, Other* Unicode category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/So/list.htm).

In Python, you can install [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), add

```
import regex
```

And then change the contents like this:

```
text = regex.sub(r'\p{So}+', '', text)
```

In Linux, you may do that with a Perl one-liner:

```
perl -i -CSD -Mutf8 -pe 's/\p{So}+//g' file
```

The `-i` option will modify the file inline, `-CSD -Mutf8` are there since I believe your file is in UTF8 encoding.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I tried applying Unicode regular expression for `\p{So}` with `sed, grep, perl` but haven't succeeded until I tried your solution. Maybe because I didn't use the options `-CSD, -Mutf8, -pe` like in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your text are using the codepage for french canadian which is `cp863`. One "hacky" method you can do without using regex is the following.

```
# this ignores any characters that are not in the standard french character page
text = "abcdeefghijkàâäèéêëîïôœùûüÿçÀÂÄÈÉÊËÎÏÔ►�▼©".encode("cp863", "ignore")
print(text.decode('cp863'))

# outputs
abcdeefghijkàâèéêëîïôùûüçÀÂÈÉÊËÎÏÔ
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is a really interesting solution and helpful to me in other problems. However, I accepted Wiktor's answer because I think it's more specific to my question (defining the special characters by some categories to remove), and it could be modified to remove other characters that we don't want by checking their corresponding Unicode categories. I upvoted your answer and another answer of yours as well :).

Comment: @Sophil no worries! you have the freedom to accept whatever answer you want :)

Comment: Thank you! Anyway, I find your solution interesting and very helpful as well! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `unicodedata` module, which is a standard module, so it should already be in your system.

You should loop every character with `unicodedata.category(`*`chr`*`)`, and check the category you want to keep, or you want to discard.

Unicode publish the *general category* values: https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/tr44-6.html#General_Category_Values

I would keep `L*` (letters), `N*` (numbers), `P*` (punctuations), and `Zs` (space). I would change other `Z*` into a space, and I would change other characters also into a space, but also save the line into a file, to check if you need to adapt rules.

Note: you may also restrict/transform other codes (e.g. opening parenthesis into just normal parenthesis, etc.) accoding your use.

Note: the above suggestion will remove also the `$` (currency symbol), you may adapt it.

Comment: Thank you! I will try your suggestions as well.